# Is Ember data support ie8,if not,what can i do to fix it

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-8, ember-data

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.9.1.js:3935
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.9.1 ember-1.9.1.js:3935
DEBUG: Ember Data : <%= versionStamp %> ember-1.9.1.js:3935
DEBUG: Handlebars : 2.0.0 ember-1.9.1.js:3935
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1 ember-1.9.1.js:3935
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

it throw an error:"the object don't support the property or function" when i give the code blow:

```
Hwv.Login = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string')
}); 

Hwv.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
    debugger;
    var login = this.store.createRecord("login");//if i remove this row,it don't throw any error;
    debugger;
        // when it in this debugger,it don't throw any error;
        //but when all of the script runned completed,it just throw an error message like above;
    return login;
        //if i change 'return login' to 'return {}',the issue still appear;
    // return {};
    }
});
```

My ask:'Is Ember data support ie8,if not,what can i do to fix it.',thanks.

Comment: I nearly forgot, are you including the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) in your page? It's required for older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ember-Data does support IE8. The reason your code isn't working is because you're trying to directly access the `store` property instead of using Ember's getter function. IE8 doesn't support Javascript computed properties so you have to use Ember's. Change the offending line to this and it should be fine:

```
var login = this.get("store").createRecord("login");
```

Comment: but it still throw the same error message in IE8 after i modified the code.
Are you sure Ember Data support IE8?
Can you give me an Simple demo for Ember Data in IE8?
Maybe,the issue appeared because the version of Ember or Ember Data.

Comment: If it doesn't work with IE8 then it's definitely a bug. Can you post the full stack trace of the error you're getting?

Comment: Thanks very much,i have found out the problem,it caused by my custom   lib code,i extend the forEach function of the array prototype in my code.